# Django - Object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python, django

I have the below code in my django project which works properly as long as the query returns items. If the Queryset returns no items (because no items are yet in the database), I get the following error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'. How Can I solve this?

Thanks !

```
date_first_cf = CashFlow.objects.filter(item__slug=itemslug).first().date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
    q = CashFlow.objects.filter(item__slug=itemslug)
    date_first_cf = q.first().date if q.exists() else None
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution